# Make a view stick to a RecyclerView item when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is what I'm trying to do : I have a horizontal RecyclerView at the bottom of a screen. When I click on an item, I want to display an arc menu above that specific item (similar to this http://www.andbrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/device-2015-04-07-165251.png) which allows some actions:

[image]

Since the arc menu cannot be contained in the item view, I used a PopupWindow managed by the item view, however I'm struggling with the positionning when I scroll on the RecyclerView.

```
public class ItemView extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Bind(R.id.avatar)
    TextView mAvatar;

    private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;

    public ItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    private void initPopup() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_arc, null);
        mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mPopupWindow.setClippingEnabled(false);
        popupView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPopupWindow.isShowing()) {
                    mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (mPopupWindow == null) {
            initPopup();
        }

        int avatarPos[] = new int[2];
        mAvatar.getLocationOnScreen(avatarPos);

        Rect avatarRect = new Rect(avatarPos[0], avatarPos[1], avatarPos[0]
                + mAvatar.getWidth(), avatarPos[1] + mAvatar.getHeight());

        mPopupWindow.getContentView().measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int contentViewHeight = mPopupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredHeight();
        int contentViewWidth = mPopupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredWidth();

        int positionX = avatarRect.centerX() - (contentViewWidth / 2);
        int positionY = avatarRect.centerY() - contentViewHeight;

        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(getRootView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, positionX, positionY);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        updateMenuPosition();
    }

    public void updateMenuPosition() {
        if (mPopupWindow != null && mPopupWindow.isShowing()) { // mPopupWindow.isShowing() is always false, why ?
            int avatarPos[] = new int[2];
            mAvatar.getLocationOnScreen(avatarPos);

            Rect avatarRect = new Rect(avatarPos[0], avatarPos[1], avatarPos[0]
                    + mAvatar.getWidth(), avatarPos[1] + mAvatar.getHeight());

            int contentViewHeight = mPopupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredHeight();
            int contentViewWidth = mPopupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredWidth();

            int positionX = avatarRect.centerX() - (contentViewWidth / 2);
            int positionY = avatarRect.centerY() - contentViewHeight;
            mPopupWindow.update(positionX, positionY, contentViewWidth, contentViewHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

- Is PopupWindow the best choice for what I'm trying to do ?
- Why *mPopupWindow.isShowing()* is always false in *updateMenuPosition()*
  ?
- How do I make the PopupWindow stick to the RecyclerView item when I
  scroll ? I read about
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#update(android.view.View,
  int, int) but it doesn't work (I removed the mPopupWindow.isShowing()). And what happens if a view is recycled
  ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using a android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in your activity_main.xml